# Can't add custom crops to the photoeditorsdk

Tags: photoeditorsdk

This shows how to add custom crops but I can't get them to show up:
https://docs.photoeditorsdk.com/guides/html5/v4-DesktopUI/features/transform

I realize there is a documentation bug where the controlsOptions object must be in the editor object but no matter where I put it, the custom crop does not show up.

EDIT: Through trial and error, I found this to be the correct format:

```
editor: {
    controlsOptions: {
        transform: {
            categories: [
            {
              identifier: 'my_transform', // A unique identifier for this transform category
              defaultName: 'My Transform', // The default translation for this transform category
              ratios: [
                {
                  identifier: 'my_custom_ratio', // A unique identifier for this ratio
                  defaultName: 'Custom Ratio', // The default translation for this ratio
                  ratio: 5 / 4, // The image ratio (a floating point number)
                  dimensions: new PhotoEditorSDK.Math.Vector2(50, 40) // Optional fixed
                }]
            }]
        }
    }
}
```